# how can i place swrevealview as a third view controller,if we make swrevealview as a initial view controller its working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

[image]

this code is for the item button.if we click it this code have to run but for me not entered into it while i make it as a third view controller.

```
 if ( revealViewController )
        {
            [self.sidebarbutton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
             NSLog(@"sidebar=%@",sidebarbutton);
            [self.sidebarbutton setAction: @selector(revealToggle:)];

            [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
        }
```

Comment: show your storyboard

Comment: r u added the front and rear view controller and at the same time r u added the set and push view controller

Comment: i have less point so i can't show

Comment: s i verified everything but its not working

Comment: its too large,if i make that as a initial view controller then its working.

Comment: show the segue connection of second view controller to thirdviewcontroller

Comment: SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController

Comment: bro if you hope with proper we can easily get the answer , u made the small mistake if you show any example or glu is easy to find the solution, else part I close your question

Comment: wait i try to add image

Comment: if u want SWRevelController as third controller u must call it from second controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step-1**

add your signup view controller to `UINavigationController`
    [image]

**Step-2**

[image]

**Step-3**

when your sign up process is completed , call the segue

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"youridentifierName" sender:self];
```

Comment: bro super i got the answer one more doubt can i use the single reveal view controller to many view controller

Comment: actually real view controller used for access the many view controllers

Comment: I am placed many view controller and each view controller have item bar if I press that the reveal view controller have to display

Comment: Is there any possibility

Comment: where u download the swlrevalVIewcontroller that place u get the sample project check once if you are not get the answer reply me

Comment: Ok bro I will check tomorrow thanks to guide me today.tomorrow morning I will check

Comment: single reveal view controller is possible to call multiple(sw_front) ,is it possible bro.

Comment: single real view controller handle the **n** times of view controllers bro, just assign root view controller of swbreval view controller you can assign "sw_front", else view controller no need bro\

Comment: i have 6 view controller first view controller is sign up ,then next view controller is swbreval,other 4 view controller have navigation bar button.each button need to access the same swbreval view [in this case problem arise for me the multiple front view is there what can i do.

Comment: u reffered the tutorial or not , I used last 8 projects in swl real view controller , you can add the only one view it is enough balance view controllers automatically added the sub view of SWL reval View controller

Comment: take this [link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/j78iq5) --- here you can get sample project